# Function communication issue with constructor and other methods?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a custom function with render & return method, it prints mere details like "Hello World" or any dumb component type. But when I try to make it little complex like props value update with some other methods it shows errors.

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstName: ''
    };
  }
  inputData = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
  }
  submitData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.firstName);
  }
  inputData()
  {
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          FirstName:
          <input type="text" name="firstName" onChange={this.inputData} />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.inputData()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In my inputdata function when I try to make it dumb component or something like it shows no error but when some other function calling like inputData and submitData like then it shows error.

Please give solution!

**Below is the Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
App._this.inputData
src/App.js:14
  11 |   };
  12 | }
  13 | inputData = (event) => {
> 14 |   this.setState({
  15 |     [event.target.name]:event.target.value
  16 |   });
  17 | }
View compiled
App.render
src/App.js:37
  34 | render() {
  35 |   return (
  36 |     <div>
> 37 |       {this.inputData()}
  38 |     </div>
  39 |   );
  40 | }
View compiled
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | registerServiceWorker();
   9 | 
  10 |
```

Comment: Paste the error and code that produces the error please.

Comment: Please check updated post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two functions with the same name: inputData. When you call this.inputData() in the render method the first one is being called, so the event is null.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help.

Comment: Becasue as I corrected typo error from inputData to Data() it's working. But suppose I tried to do it fat arrow function like 

Data = () => "then function content" it shows error. So, I'm asking that fat arrow can't be used such like this???

Comment: The problem was not the arrow function but the name of the functions. You had to functions with the same name: inputData.

Imagine that you have an empty file with these functions:

var a = function() {
 console.log('One');
}

function a() {
 console.log('Two');
}

a()

Which one will be called?

Comment: I got your point thanks for clearing, really appreciate that!

Comment: No a problem. 

A popular naming convention in react is to prefix the functions that render react components with render. In your case you can use renderInput instead of inputData, for the second inputData that returns a react component.